# Custom Template not working/Page blank showing "members-grid.php" ( ultimate member plugin) Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I want to modify member list page "`members-grid.php`" and create to my active theme folder.

I have created structure

Copy:

```
wp-content/plugins/ultimate-member/templates/members-grid.php
```

to paste theme filder:

```
wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/ultimate-member/templates/members-grid.php
```

See plugin Documentation:

https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/1516-templates-map
https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/121-using-html-in-e-mail-templates

Its Not working as expected. Please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYFBt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQtx0.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove templates folder from your theme. Remove templates folder and simply add members-grid.php file inside ultimate-member folder.

Comment: You told :
wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/ultimate-member/members-grid.php
and add template name:
<?php /* Template: Member Grid */ ?>
Already try not working,page blank showing

Comment: I want to override member list page (members-grid.php) and create custom template theme folder.